# NSLayoutConstraint not updating every time

Tags: ios, swift, nslayoutconstraint

I was testing with `NSLayoutConstraint` and found that layouts are not updating every time.
Here is my `ViewController`'s IB.
[image: Took constraints in IB]
Here I've taken `IBAction` for `valueChange` of `Stepper`

```
@IBAction func handleStepperValueChanged(_ sender: UIStepper) {
    progressBar.progress = Float(sender.value / sender.maximumValue)
    lblProgress.text = String(format: "%.2f %", progressBar.progress)

    updateMyConstraint()
}
func updateMyConstraint() {
    for constraints in lblProgress.constraints {
        if constraints.firstAttribute == .width {
            lblProgress.removeConstraint(constraints)
        }
    }
    let multiplier = CGFloat(progressBar.progress)
    let constLblWidth = NSLayoutConstraint(item: lblProgress, attribute: .width, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: progressBar, attribute: .width, multiplier: multiplier, constant: 0.0)
    constLblWidth.priority = .defaultHigh
    lblProgress.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    constLblWidth.isActive = true
    lblProgress.updateConstraints()
}
```

and here is my output. (which is not updating each time when I update Stepper's value)
[image: 0.40]
[image: 0.50]
[image: 0.60]

Is there something that I'm missing to update layouts?
Please help me to solve this.
Each time update ProgressBar label also should increase its width.

I've also tried to update layout via below statements.

```
self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
self.view.layoutSubviews()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here

```
lblProgress.removeConstraint(constraints)
```

the constraint should be removed from the parent of both `lblProgress` and `progressBar`
 because the constraint is between them

```
  func updateMyConstraint() {
    for constraints in self.view.constraints {

        if constraints.identifier == "someIdentifier"  && constraints.firstAttribute == .width {
              print(constraints)
              self.view.removeConstraint(constraints)
        }
    }
    let multiplier = CGFloat(progressBar.progress)
    let constLblWidth = NSLayoutConstraint(item: lbl, attribute: .width, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: progressBar, attribute: .width, multiplier: multiplier, constant: 0.0)
    constLblWidth.priority = .required
    lbl.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    constLblWidth.isActive = true
    constLblWidth.identifier = "someIdentifier"
    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
}
```

`constLblWidth.isActive = true` is originally add the constraint to the shared parent between the 2 items which is self.view in this case , so when you remove the constraint you should remove it from self.view you can verify that by printing the constraints here is a run with my edit

[image]

Comment: removed from progressBar, still same effect

Comment: I think you're removing constraint of self.view and adding to lbl.

Comment: the reason I've set priority to high cause if I set to required then it was also creating UI problem while updating stepper's value

Comment: set it to high was the reason it was broken and not updating the width of the progresslbl

Comment: use .constant property of constraints to increase or decrease size of view